# Can NOPI/Volatile tables in teradata be partitioned on basis of a column?

Tags: teradata

I wanted to ask if NOPI tables can be portioned on a column in Teradata or not.
Also I am assuming that we can partition volatile table as well can anyone conform on both?

Answer (score 1):

Columnar partitioning is implemented since Teradata 14 and before TD15.10 a Columnar Table must have no Primary Index (i.e. NoPI).

Volatile (& Global Temporary) Tables can be row-partitioned (iirc since TD14), but not Columnar.

But why didn't you simply try it on your own?

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning means in Teradata Partitioned Primary Index (alias PPI), so when you create table with No Primary Index, it cannot be partitioned. Also I think, it does not make sense to do it.
Volatile tablle and Global Temporary tables cannot have PPI.

Comment: #1: No PPI, but Columnar partitioning. #2: Of course VT & GTT can have a PPI (since TD14)